# UNIX command to add comma and space

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, scripting

I have a file that looks like

```
$ cat IP
10.3.1.1
10.4.1.1
10.6.3.1
10.19.4.2
10.22.3.4
```

How do I make it look like:

```
$ cat IP 
10.3.1.1, 10.4.1.1, 10.6.3.1, 10.19.4.2, 10.22.3.4
```

Answer (score 17):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/, / unless eof' IP
```

Add the `-i` option to edit the file `i`nplace. Or `-i.orig` to edit it in place but keep the original as `IP.orig`.

With the `zsh` shell, you can also load those IPs into an array with:

```
ips=( ${(f)"$(<IP)"} )
```

And then write them back `j`oined with commas with:

```
print -r -- ${(j[, ])ips} > IP
```

Contrary to the perl one which processes one line at a time, that one loads the file whole in memory.

Two other differences:

- empty lines are discarded
- a newline character is always added at the end even if the original file didn't contain any like for an empty file or a file whose last line was not properly delimited.

Answer (score 7):

With the GNU implementation of `sed`:

```
sed -z 's/\n*$//;s/\n/, /g;s/$/\n/' IP
```

Comment: The output is missing a trailing newline character though, which you could add back with `$s/$/\n/`

Comment: i have changed that   ....

Comment: Thanks, for posting an answer. This _should_ be an answer and not a comment. Please never post answers in comments, we need them as answers so they can be voted on.

Comment: `s/$/\n/` adds a newline at the end of every (NUL-delimited here with -z) record, `$s/$/\n/` adds it only to the end of the last record (would only make a difference if the file contained NUL characters).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps

```
perl -e 'print join(", ", map { chomp; $_ } <>), "\n"' IP
```

Or

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", c, $0; c = ", " } END { print "" }' IP
```

Or for a quick and dirty hack, subject to constraints on the number of lines in your file (potentially as few as 8000), and bearing in mind that `xargs` wasn't really designed for this

```
xargs <IP | sed 's/ /, /g'
```

All these produce the same output from your example data set:

```
10.3.1.1, 10.4.1.1, 10.6.3.1, 10.19.4.2, 10.22.3.4
```

You can then redirect that output to a temporary file and then overwrite the original. Here, replace `command_from_above` with your choice of any command (here in this answer or anyone else's) that writes the changes to *stdout* rather than to the original file:

```
command_from_above >"IP.$$.tmp" && mv -f -- "IP.$$.tmp" IP
rm -f -- "IP.$$.tmp"
```

Comment: `xargs` run `/bin/echo` in batches for each word in the input, so that will fall apart if there are many lines or as soon as the lines contain anything but single IP addresses.

Comment: The example file gives no indication that there might be anything other than a single IP address or line. Neither does it give any indication of file size. (That could work either in my favour or against it, I agree, @StéphaneChazelas)

Comment: `xargs` (without the `-r`/`-0` GNU extensions) is bad enough when used for what it's meant to (pass arguments to a command when read from a stream), I'd rather we stop advertising its use for something it's not designed for and where it's very bad at: doing text processing. While the OP might get away with using it with their dataset, other people may come here with different datasets and get the impression that it can be used to join lines with spaces. You could at least point out the many limitations.

Answer (score 5):

With bash, zsh, or ksh:

```
( x=$(cat IP) && echo "${x//$'\n'/, }" > IP )
```

- Create a subshell to prevent the `x` variable from leaking out
- Set `x` to the contents of the `IP` file, including all newlines except the last
- Replace newlines in `x` with `,`  (comma,space)
- Echo the result back to the `IP` file, adding (back) a final newline

It works even if there are spaces in the lines, but it sounds like you don't need that. However in zsh if the data contains backslashes they are interpreted, often producing wrong results, unless you use `echo -E`.

Comment: The builtin  `echo` or bash and ksh can also expand backslash-escapes (as POSIX requires!) depending on how those shells  were built or invoked or the environment. You may also have problems if the first line starts with a `-`. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) for details.

Comment: In those shells, you can also do `x=$(<IP)`.

Comment: I'm curious: Why the parens to create a subshell? Is the purpose just to scope the variable `x` so it doesn't remain in memory after the command is complete?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, see the first item: *Create a subshell to prevent the x variable from leaking out*

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR==1) ? "" : ", ", $0}END{print ""}'
```

This will prefix every line except for the first with a comma.

Answer (score 3):

Adding comma with `sed` but excluding the last line, then replacing every new line with space:

```
sed '$!s/$/,/' file | paste -sd ' ' -
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *AWK*:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s", a "," OFS} {a=$0}END {print a}'
```

If only comma is needed without space and all records have only one fields, then `datamash` may be used.

```
$ datamash -W collapse 1 <file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help everyone.
Many good answers.  Please let me know if or how I can show appreciation, by feedback, points, etc.
I am new to this.
Thanks agsain

Answer (score 2):

If you can't remember / don't want to learn the more powerful tools like awk and sed (and don't mind a trailing comma) here's a simple and understandable solution:

```
OUT=""; for i in $(cat IP); do OUT="$OUT $i,"; done; echo $OUT
```

Output:

```
10.3.1.1, 10.4.1.1, 10.6.3.1, 10.19.4.2, 10.22.3.4,
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t actually care about the space after each comma, this is what `paste` is good at:

```
paste -sd , -
```

You could restore the space by piping to sed if you know that no values contain a comma:

```
… | sed s/,/,\ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '$++ && print ", "; .print;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'slurp.chomp.subst(:global, / \n /, ", ").put;'  file
```

Herein are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages.

In the first example, the file is read-in using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags, which auto-chomps (removes) the trailing newline by default. When the anonymous `$++` post-incrementing counter variable reads  the first line (i.e. `$++` equals zero), the `", "` comma-space is skipped while the line is output without a newline terminator using `.print`. Note: `.print` is short for `$_.print` meaning to print the `$_` topic variable. Otherwise, for every subsequent line, a comma-space is printed followed by the line (i.e. topic) itself.

In the second example, the file is `slurp`ed, i.e. read-into memory all at once, preserving internal/trailing newlines, etc. The trailing newline is `chomp`ed off, internal `\n` newlines are `subst`ituted globally with `", "` comma-space, and the resultant file is out`put`, which (in contrast to `print`) adds a newline at the end of the string (here, the end of the file).

Sample Input:

```
10.3.1.1
10.4.1.1
10.6.3.1
10.19.4.2
10.22.3.4
```

Sample Output (both code examples):

```
10.3.1.1, 10.4.1.1, 10.6.3.1, 10.19.4.2, 10.22.3.4
```

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ( I don't know if it's posix ):

```
sed -n -e '1h;1!H;${g;s/\n/, /g;p;}' data
```

Save all lines to the `h`old space and then, at the end, `s`ubstitute all newlines with a `,` .

---

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (this should be posix portable. I don't remember if all [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) let you unset the `RS` variable but i tested it with the `--posix` and `--lint` set to fatal in [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) and it worked ):

```
awk -v RS= 'gsub(/\n/, ", ")' data
```

Unset the `R`ecord `S`eparator variable to get all the file content as a single line and then replace all the new line charcter's with a `,`

Comment: Note  that empty RS is the paragraph mode, where records are separated by sequences of empty lines, not the [slurp mode](/q/304457)

Comment: The `sed` command is POSIX, as long as the input is guaranteed to be no larger than 10 x LINE_MAX byte large and is valid text in the user's locale

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes for awk. I don't mean that unsetting RS will place awk in slurp mode, it's just my exression limit with english language ( i will edit ).
Thanks for sed clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a simple way to do it:

```
sed 's/$/,/' |xargs echo |sed 's/,$//'
```

However, it would fail:

- for very long files (that exceed the maximum size of a program's arguments on your system),
- if the first line of your file looks like an option to your system's `echo` program.

Edit: see the comments for more failure modes. Only use this for short files with no characters that are special to `xargs` or `echo`.

Comment: Also fails if lines contain single quotes, double quotes or backslashes or whitespace (list of which varying with locale and xargs implementation) and depending on the xargs implementation: if the input cannot be decoded as text in the locale, if there are words bigger than some limit which can be ridiculously low on some systems (I've seen 255). See also my comment to [Chris' answer](/a/764823). Note that `echo` is the default command run by `xargs`, so `xargs echo` is the same as `xargs` alone.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I had no idea `xargs` processed quotes in its arguments. (And I wonder why: `xargs` gets its input via `argv` and can just pass them on to `exec(ve)` since most programs work perfectly fine with arguments containing quotes. Historical reasons, I guess. An option to suppress that behaviour without resorting to `-0` would be nice.)

Comment: `xargs` gets a list of *words* on stdin which have to be delimited in some way (and quotes are used to escape the delimiters (and other types of quotes)) and passes those *words* across (the `x` in its name) as arguments to commands. To delimit words on newline only with no way to escape those newlines (and thus no way for a command argument to contain a newline), see the `-d '\n'` of the GNU implementation of `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Some more simple variations:

```
cat IP | sed 's/$/, /' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/, $/\n/'
```

or

```
cat IP | perl -pe 's/\n/, /' | perl -pe 's/, $/\n/'
```